# Mod Rewrite and GET data - works on one but not another

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get

Stumped here and appreciate the help.

creating a site with double optin registration - uses _GET in an emailed URL to finish subscription.
After subscribing I have a link that allows them to access back issues using _GET

1. the link in the email looks like:
   http://173.201.224.43/Jason_Borjeson/jeba2012/site/subscription_manager?act=1&h=a2df4b90c3fc3d061838661886e321d1
2. and the link on the web page looks like: http://173.201.224.43/Jason_Borjeson/jeba2012/site/past_issues?c=17&a=list

if need be you can use link #1 to get to link #2 (purple text link to the right of the form button in the table data) as the site is still under development.

all pages on the site run through mod_rewrite. #1 above works while #2 yields a 404 (server stated - not php/database generated).

the text between / and ? is used to select the page from the database while the variables after the ? are for additional info to be shown.

the htaccess file is as follows:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Jason_Borjeson/jeba2012/site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^css/css\.css$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

link #1 makes it through the process as expected, but link #2 seems to slip through the crack. If I QSA the rule I get an internal server error on both.

I just want all info to be passed and am parsing it in my php code.

Just as an FYI - _POST seems to be working no sweat. Also hosting on GoDaddy (if that makes a difference)

Thanks again!

Comment: Just tested this. Its working for both the URL's here. if you have access to apache's `.conf` files, enable rewrite logging. By doing this:`RewriteEngine on` 
`RewriteLog /etc/httpd/logs/rewrite.log` 
`RewriteLogLevel 9` in your `VirtualHost`.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey - thanks I'll give that a try - just retried this morning, flushed cache and still not working here.

Comment: I gave it a try and received  an internal server error. Total bummer as I really want to know what the heck is going on.

Comment: you added the code into your `virtualhost` section right? and also change the `RewriteLog /etc/httpd/logs/rewrite.log` to a path where you have proper access to.

Comment: no, I am really a newb when it comes to htaccess files and just use the basic like wordpress has. I have no idea what the virtualhost section is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the slightest change in the second URL makes the rewrite kick in. I have to believe the rewrite conditions are not being met -- that there is perhaps a directory named "past_issues" on your system.

Comment: There isn't one within the RewriteBase and I am pretty sure there isn't one in the directories above, but I'll check to be sure.

Comment: Couldn't find a directory, or file, named past_issues. I'm wondering if GoDaddy has some sort of filter for it for logging old account tickets. So I guess I will be renaming the "file" in the database. Thanks again!